# Properly formatting NSTimer in Swift

Tags: swift, string-formatting

Would like to ask, how to properly format an `NSTimer` in the interval of `0.01`?
I would like to have something like `00:00.00` (mins, sec, msec)

When I run my code:

...

```
@IBAction func btn_play(sender: AnyObject) {
        timer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(0.01, target: self, selector: Selector("result"), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
    }
```

...

```
func result() {
    count++
    lbl_time.text = String(count)
}
```

...

I receive something like `1123` ( stands for 11 seconds 23 msecs)
How would you transform it to eg:

`00:11.23`

I've tried some stuff with "substring" but with no sucess. I'm new to Swift, so I'm not aware what possibilities I have here. thx!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use integer division `/` and modulo `%` to calculate the values for minutes, seconds, and hundredths of a second, and then use the `String` convenience initializer which takes a `format` string to add the leading zeros and colons:

```
let count = 1234
let str = String(format:"%02d:%02d:%02d", (count/6000)%100, (count/100)%60, count%100)
```

This functionality comes from the `Foundation` framework.  To use this convenience initializer for `String`, you must `import Foundation` (note: `Foundation` is imported by both `import UIKit` (iOS) and `import Cocoa` (OS X), so you usually don't `import Foundation` explicitly).

The `NSString` formatting methods follow [the IEEE printf specification](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/printf.html).

Comment: The first term should probably be something like `count/6000` to give the minutes.

Comment: Good point @MartinR.  I was focused on the formatting, and not enough on the math.

Comment: Thx a lot guys! works like a charm! Will google a bit now for format. To see what everything is possible!Thx